# android studio buttons not working

Tags: java, android

it's my first time posting a question and i already tried more than 5 solutions being told in this site, but none of them works for me, the problem is the buttons are clickable, but not going anywhere i wanted them to, but the main page login button that leads to this page works with the same exact code, below is the menu code

```
   public class AdminMenu extends Activity{

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_menu);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.staff);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stock);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.incoming);
        b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.outgoing);
        b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, StaffSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, StockSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, IncomingSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, OutgoingSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging Out...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

then here is the xml for the app interface

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="STAFF"
        android:id="@+id/staff"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#52cc85"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contextClickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="STOCK"
        android:id="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_below="@+id/staff"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/staff"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/staff"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/staff"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/staff"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#52cccc"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="INCOMING SHIPMENT"
        android:id="@+id/incoming"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/stock"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#52cc85"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="OUTGOING SHIPMENT"
        android:id="@+id/outgoing"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incoming"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/incoming"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/incoming"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/incoming"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/incoming"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="#52cccc"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="LOGOUT"
        android:id="@+id/logout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/outgoing"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/outgoing"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/outgoing" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.reversesky.mwms">

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".User.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".User.AdminMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".User.StaffMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".User.StaffSelection">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IS.IncomingSelection">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OS.OutgoingSelection">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Stock.StockSelection">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".User.CreateStaff">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".IS.CreateIncoming">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Stock.CreateStock">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OS.CreateOutgoing">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the UI[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMd1u.jpg)

Comment: i don't think its a good idea to use setContentView many times in the same activity. Instead start a new activity on button click

Comment: start a new activity using intent?

Comment: use  fragment for better performance.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but i have close to zero idea of how to use fragments, do you know any guide for it?

Comment: use fragments with view pager for the good solution and can you edit the question with UI?

Comment: You should use Fragments instead of switching different layouts in activity.

Comment: do you have any links to fragment guides that is easy to understand for beginners? thank you

Comment: Just Comment finish() below startActivity(intent) and then check it again ..

Comment: already tried the finish() and still not working

Comment: Try to Invalidate Caches and restart android studio (Go to File Menu) and then clean build it..

Comment: nope, it doesn't work also

Answer (score 0):

[image: AdminMenu View]
[image: StaffSelection view]

Replace your code like this,

AdminMenu.class

```
    public class AdminMenu extends Activity {

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_menu);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.staff);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stock);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incoming);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.outgoing);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMenu.this, StaffSelection.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

StaffSelection.class

```
    public class StaffSelection extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".AdminMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StaffSelection"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        />
</application>
```

According to you add your class and other details.I have done only for Staff button click.

Comment: show me what you have tried,also try to add manifest like this

Comment: don't know how if i can comment with the codes, but i edited to include using intent

Comment: You need to add <intent-filter> only with the main activity(means your starting activity)Rest you can add like what i have mentioned in my answer

Comment: okay i fixed the manifest already, but it's not working still

Comment: sorry, but how do i send or do you want me to add another activity to the question?

Comment: wait let me check what is the issue with your code...Here it worked..i will update my code..do like that

Comment: Check my answer..its working perfectly...do like that

Comment: Have you tried with my code?it will work dear.Because i have tested here.Clean your project and again rebuild it okay

Comment: i just edited the code i posted and i don't see if there is any difference between our code

Comment: it is still not working, is it better if i create a new project instead? i'm honestly frustrated by this simple problem, and i don't know why my first button for my login worked but this one does not

Comment: but i have used your code only na...you just create new one and try with my code

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Alternative solutions ,

1. [ViewAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) : This is useful for showing a quick animation, if you want to change the view multiple times in quick succession.
2. [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) : Instead of re-drawing the entire view, you can switch out fragments. Each fragment is a kind of mini activity, and overall this will contain the code much better.
3. [Start New Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) : Pass information to an activity to help it set up. The first activity passes information to a common second activity, which knows how to set itself up based off of the information it receives from the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I tried with your code, it works fine for me

Comment: He need to redirect to another activity..Its just showing toast na

Comment: @SIndhu Yep !! thanks :) I see your answer you are a step ahead from my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up Your solution a little bit.

Entire `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  <activity android:name=".AdminMenuActivity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity android:name=".CreateIncomingActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".CreateOutgoingActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".CreateStaffActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".CreateStockActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".IncomingSelectionActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".OutgoingSelectionActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".StaffMenuActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".StaffSelectionActivity"/>
  <activity android:name=".StockSelectionActivity"/>

</application>
```

Please keep in mind You should align activities names as you wish.

In my recreation, every single activity (except `AdminMenuActivity` to demonstrate usage) is as silly as:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tommus.buttonsnotworking;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class CreateIncomingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_incoming);
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind you should use proper layout id in all activities.

Again, in my recreation every single layout (except `activity_admin_menu` to demonstrate usage) is as silly as:

Now is the important part.

My `activity_menu_admin` is the same as yours:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:background="#52cc85"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="STAFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/staff"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#52cccc"
    android:text="STOCK"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stock"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#52cc85"
    android:text="INCOMING SHIPMENT"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/outgoing"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_below="@+id/incoming"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#52cccc"
    android:text="OUTGOING SHIPMENT"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/outgoing"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/outgoing"
    android:layout_below="@+id/outgoing"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="LOGOUT"
    />
```

`AdminMenuActivity` has some changes:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tommus.buttonsnotworking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AdminMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_menu);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.staff);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stock);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incoming);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.outgoing);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               navigateToActivity(CreateStaffActivity.class);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                navigateToActivity(CreateStockActivity.class);
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                navigateToActivity(CreateIncomingActivity.class);
            }
        });
        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                navigateToActivity(CreateOutgoingActivity.class);
            }
        });
        b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging Out...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                navigateToActivity(LoginActivity.class);
            }
        });
    }

    private void navigateToActivity(Class<?> activityClass) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am opening new activities with a use of `Intent`s. This way I am sure when creating a new activity I have an activity with proper layout and not messed up ids.

Comment: thanks for the different approach using navigateToActivity, but i tried just now and it's still not working

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/tommus/stackoverflow/tree/master/android-studio-buttons-not-working) you have a full working repository with example. Please clone by yourself, compile and test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please remove line "android:contextClickable="true" from your b1 button in your xml file and then try again.

Comment: Hi russel23, have you tried with removing "android:contextClickable="true" from your b1 button in your xml file.